# Stripe connect express onboarding flow

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to understand what is the best way to integrate stripe connect express in my marketplace.

So far I am able to:

1. collect some information on my marketplace
2. create a stripe express account with /v1/accounts
3. create a person with person API
4. create an account link
5. onboard the connected user in test mode

Basically following guidelines on https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts

I've noticed that even though I pre-populate the company details and person details (representative, owner, director,..) the user is still able to update everything.

Is there a way to prevent user editing the pre-populated info and potentially creating a mismatch of the data I am staring on my platform?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Express, you don't need to, *and can't*, create a Person object, or supply KYC information(identity verification details like DOB/address/national IDs etc). That's intentionally all handled for you by Stripe and it asks for everything required without you needing to collect/process/store this kind of sensitive data on your own server. I think you can pass it to /v1/accounts because it's the same API as Custom, but it's silently ignored for Express.

I'd recommend just not collecting this information if you don't actually need to manage it yourself, and letting Stripe handle it as part of the Express onboarding.

If you do want/need to/are compliant with relevant data protection requirements, to manage this personal info, you could collect it and use Custom accounts instead, which let you pass this KYC information directly to the API and it will pre-fill as you expect. But there is significantly more integration work required for Custom so I'd go with my original recommendation.